# styling with numbers for number formats using css

Tags: php, echo, number-formatting

when using the number_format is it possible to customize the font or size found sites that say you cant but just want to double check ?

```
$em = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users`"); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($em) > 0){     
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($em)){
      $amount = $row['amount'];
      echo number_format($amount, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: "is it possible to customize the font" - yes, of course. Why not use common HTML markup for this, as you would do with all other output?

Comment: Just tried that now sorry having a slow day thanks though :)

Comment: Just to be clear, `number_format` *returns a string value* and that's all. There is no inherent relationship between CSS and any given PHP function, where some functions' return values, strings or integers or floats, would be less compatible with CSS (that you would typically apply to HTML tags surrounding your output text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use a CSS class for it or use inline style like this, here is the example:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($em)){

        $amount = $row['amount'];
    
        $formated_number = number_format($amount, 0);

        echo '<span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;">'.$formated_number.'</span>'
         }
```